# Rewrite rule for wordpress site installed in subdirectory (not a multisite)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have copied a wordpress site over from a server I need to work on and set it up on localhost, the wordpress folder is set up as a subdirectory of root.

My only problem is my links are redirecting to the root instead of the wpfolder eg. and file paths do not have the wpfolder name in them.

Example:

ht.p://localhost/wpfolder/wp-content/themes/tbt/_inc/js/functions.js

Should be:

ht.p://localhost/root/wpfolder/wp-content/themes/tbt/_inc/js/functions.js

I have followed all the instructionss from the codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install and have everything working except I have been struggling to get my links and files to redirect to the right filepath.

I have saved general settings, refreshed permalinks and restarted the server in that order. I have also confirmed the htaccess is being read and the database is being read fine with all posts available in wp-admin.

The confusing thing is that even though the original site on the server has wp installed in a subdirectory I dont see how its redirecting. The site structure of the local copy is as follows:

```
/localhost/site_root/wpfolder
```

and original:

```
user@domain/public_html/wpfolder
```

When exporting the db I have set the addresses are as follows:

SITE ADDRESS
remote: //www.domain.com, 
local: //localhost/siteroot/

WP ADDRESS 
remote: /home/siteuser/public_html,
local: /siteroot/wpfolder 
(I dont get why this doesnt point to the subdirectory on the original site?)

htaccess at remote root:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /order-online/order-now/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sitename.com.au/order-online/order-now/$1 [R,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and my local htaccess at the root written automatically after migrating the db and saving all settings in wp-admin:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /order-online/order-now/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.originalsitedomain.com/order-online/order-now/$1 [R,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /siteroot/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /siteroot/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My local index.php at the root (same as remote):

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wpfolder/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Currently for example instead of my links taking me to localhost/site_root/link there are going to localhost/link and 404'ing.

I haven't been able to get this to work as I dont fully understand it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/siteroot$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wpfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wpfolder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/siteroot$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wpfolder/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

But it is not in the htaccess of the original site anyway (why i dont understand). Im all out of ideas for the love of jeebus can anyone help with the rewrite above or suggest what I may be doing wrong?

Let me know if I can provide more info.

Thanks.

EDIT: I cannot understand why there is a problem if I just copied over the original site! NOne of the original link or urls are prefixed by the root folder.

EDIT2: Some example html that 404's. Only the header displays (due to  `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wpfolder/wp-blog-header.php' )`).

header.php

```
if (!is_404() && $ie7==false && !isset($_GET['preview'])) {
    echo '<script src="/tbtwp/wp-content/themes/tbt/_inc/js/functions.js"></script>';
}
```

MENU:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-home <?php if(is_front_page()){ echo 'current_page_item' ; }?>"><a tabindex="1" href="/" title="home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-about-us"><a tabindex="1" href="/about-us/" title="about-us">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="nav-the-store"><a tabindex="1" href="/the-store/" title="the-store">The Store</a></li>
        <li class="nav-catering"><a tabindex="1" href="/catering/" title="catering">Catering</a></li>
        <li class="nav-order-online <?php if(is_page('order-online/order-now')){ echo 'current_page_item' ; }?>"><a tabindex="1" href="/order-online/" title="order-online">Order Online</a></li>
        <li class="nav-our-stories"><a tabindex="1" href="/our-stories/" title="our-stories">Our Stories</a></li>
        <li class="nav-contact"><a tabindex="1" href="/contact/" title="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are any links working or are all links broken? I'd recommend running a serialized search and replace on the url shard using [interconnect/it PHP database search and replace tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) (no affiliation)

Comment: All the links go to the root localhost/link instead of localhost/root/link. I will take a look at your link now.

Comment: I dont think this is the problem as dbmigrate handles this when I export the db. Its more the issue of why would the remote site resolve to www.domain.com/page.php when my local site resolves to http://localhost/page.php (404) and not http://localhost/sitefolder/page.php

Comment: Ah, @JPB I must have glanced over where you said <blockquote>When exporting the db I have set the addresses are as follows:</blockquote>

Comment: That menu code you pasted is strange indeed as wordpress-generated menus typically contain absolute URL's unless a theme function or plugin function is overriding it.... would you be able to provide a list of plugins and what theme you're using in your answer?

Comment: Menu is static. Its a custom theme and no fancy plugins just ACF and Gravity forms. Menus not available in wp-admin. This is the challenge when taking over a random site. Ill take another look at the functions.

Comment: Ok the menu is handled with ajax but it doenst have any relevance. The core issue is why does the remote site resovle to root even though wp is in a subdirectory. I think if everything was localhost/sitefolder/... it would work but its just localhost.

Comment: Well if it's a custom theme and the developer is using something like Roots Soil Root Relative URLs https://github.com/roots/soil (either as a plugin or directly in functons.php) this could definitely be effecting your site.

Comment: Thank. Ive actually narrowed it down to the use of ajax in a smooth scroll function that is based on / which is causing the 404. This is because the file structure of local is local/site/wpinstall and the remote site is domain/wpinstall and resolving to root locally goes to localhost not site . Im going to give this a shot when im in the office later:  define( 'WP_HOME' , 'http://localhost/site' ); define( 'WP_SITEURL' , 'http://localhost/site' ); thanks for your input i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

What has worked for me is following the "Relocate" alternative.

You define RELOCATE true in your wp-config.
Then you enter your local wp-login.php url into your browser and login.
Check that url in the browser is the local one.
Go to General settings and review the site url and the wp url.
The site url would normally not have the subfolder wehre wp is installed. And the wp url will.
Then you save your settings.
If you ar using permalinks go to permalinks settings and save them.

The last part is to copy the .htaccess and index.php from the wordpress folder to the root folder, and edit the index.php:
where it says `require('./wp-blog-header.php');` change it to `require('./<replace with wp subfolder name>/wp-blog-header.php');`

VERY IMPORTANT!:
Finally remove the define('RELOCATE',true); from wp-config.
(not comment, REMOVE)

References:
[How to change URL using RELOCATE method](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Comment: Ok will try that now. Thanks.

Comment: No Joy. This doesnt seem to address the issue of the links not being prefixed with the correct filepath although It;s handy to know. Im thinking the solution has to do with a rewrite.

Comment: If you are refering to the links that are hardcoded in the "content" of you pages, that is a totally different thing. You have to run sql commands to update those links.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction please, although I dont fully understand why that would need changing if the original site was installed in a subdirectory with the same name.

Comment: I just read your post again. Where you mention "WP ADDRESS remote: /home/siteuser/public_html, local: /siteroot/wpfolder (I dont get why this doesnt point to the subdirectory on the original site?)", are you entering a url or a path? It should be a URL including the subfolder where wp is installed.

Comment: In wordpress under general they are paths but when I exported from migrateDB its a url and a path. The path doent seem to effect anything though. Remote path: /home/theblack/public_html Local path: /siteroot/wpfolder

Comment: Look at thsi picture. Both are urls. http://imh01-inmotionhosting1.netdna-ssl.com/support/images/stories/wordpress/change-url/url-settings-in-wordpress-dashboard.png (it is a random picture I took from internet to show you as an example)

Comment: Yeah thats what I have in general settings.

Comment: If you target you site url in your browser does it open it correctly or does it fail with some 404 or does it take you to your prod site?

Comment: It takes me to the local dev site but only displays the header. In the local wp-admin all the posts are there so db has migrated ok as far as I can tell. I'll add some html to my question.

Comment: Regarding the .htaccess the one you have now is the one that starts with "RewriteBase /siteroot/" or the one that starts with "RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/siteroot$". It should be the one you copied from the wp installation to root after the relocate and saving permalinks.

Comment: The first one is the one I copied from the remote site and it was overwritten with the 'general' setting in wp, Im not really sure how to configure the second one but its confusing as thats the recommended way in the codex. Im not currently using the second one.

Comment: The .htaccess you should use is the one generated after the relocate process. And you copy it from the wp folder where it is generated to the root folder (one up). Assuming you also did the update to the index.php, can you try entering manually the full url  (http://....)  to one of the links of your menu?

Comment: I tried entering the url but it seems like there something else going on here to do with ajax and the way the page is built.